# Hydro Ubuntu 12.04 and Stage - Can't open roomba-world

Tags: ros, simulation, stage, stageros, stage-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using hydro and Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers). I downloaded stage_controllers, but when I try to launch the world this is what I get. Can anybody help me? From another question i read that maybe there's a problem with the lasers/rangers terminology, but  from there I couldn't find a solution. I'm sorry I'm very new to ROS and I'm trying my best.

```
    rosrun stage_ros stageros stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world 
 [Loading stage_controllers/world/roomba-wander.world]
err: Model type laser not found in model typetable (/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-stage-4.1.1-6precise-20140819-1748/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
err: Unknown model type laser in world file. (/tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-stage-4.1.1-6precise-20140819-1748/libstage/world.cc CreateModel)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202313/hydro-ubuntu-12.04-and-stage---can%27t-open-roomba-world/) by [Pandamonium](https://answers.ros.org/users/21553/pandamonium/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Richard Hou](https://answers.ros.org/users/27763/richard-hou/) on 2016-08-16**:
Hi,Can you tell me where the code is it,Because I can't find the code from the address(http://mobotica.googlecode.com/files/stage_controllers.tar.gz ).Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I didn't look at the code, but I think roomba-world map file should be updated, changing laser model to ranger model.

Here is an example of this modification on another map file, maybe you could try something similar:

https://github.com/gustavovelascoh/stage_ros/commit/d6c9927b5414c715bf3670eb646263929358492f

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0